# NSUserDefaults / SharedPreferences do we have any thing similar in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

i'm new to Angularjs-2.3 TypeScript. i have a scenario which that i needs to save userId in the app, So that can be access any where in the app.

if i was using android or iOS i will use those NSUserDefaults and SharedPreferences. How can i do the same thing in the TypeScript for native apps for android and iOS. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the way to do it. using application-settings it is so simple.

link-> https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/application-settings

this are the steps:

import application-settings in the file needs to save or read

```
import { getString, setString } from "application-settings";
```

to set values

```
setString(yourKey,appropriateValue);
```

to read values

```
getString(yourKey);
```